# How to securely decode an encoded URL?

Tags: encoding, url

I received an email from a trusted source with a hyperlink but the link is URL encoded. I want to try to decode it to inspect it because various browsers are rejecting it, perhaps it was mangled in transit. But I don't want to write a software program or any software code to decode it.

I want to use a secure trustworthy public service that doesn't harvest my submission.

Does such a thing exist?

I googled around but the various available URL decoders are from unknown-to-me sources that don't present clear evidence of highly trustworthiness and a verifiable commitment to not harvest my submission:

- https://www.urldecoder.org/
- https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/
- https://www.base64decode.org/
- https://www.urldecoder.io/

Answer (score 2):

You can use a built-in Javascript function [decodeURI()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_decodeuri.asp) to decode URLs.

This should work in your browser's Javascript console:

```js
console.log(decodeURI('<your url here>'));
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use a secure trustworthy public service that doesn't harvest my submission.

Based on your criteria, the only way a service can *become* trustworthy is by 1) performing the operation entirely client-side, and 2) you inspecting its source code before use.

As it happens, most sites you linked to are client-side JavaScript apps, and in particular the site `https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/` consists of exactly one self-contained HTML file with only 3 lines worth of JS code in the "decode" function.

It's then up to you to interpret the evidence that *has* been presented.

> But I don't want to write a software program or any software code to decode it.

I wrote the necessary software code:

```
echo "<URL>" | ruby -ruri -e 'puts URI.decode(gets)'

echo "<URL>" | perl -pe 's/%([A-Fa-f0-9]{2})/pack("C", hex($1))/gse'

echo "<URL>" | python3 -c 'import sys, urllib.parse; print(urllib.parse.unquote(sys.stdin.read()))'
```